Customize TOC in pandoc docx output
Is there a way to customize TOC for docx output? I'm trying to:

Change toc name (replace 'table of contents' with Custom text)
Put 'title' page and 'authors' page before toc

I use .md input files
Since docx output doesn't have a template, only reference docx, I cant really specify what comes before toc.
Currently I use command like this:
pandoc -s ${metadata.includes} -o "${outpuPath} -t docx --toc

Plus lua-fulter
Where metadata.includes contains file paths in order I need them to appear in document
Tried to pass variable toc-title to pandoc and change the order of - - toc argument in command line. Changes nothing.
